# Event 1014: Name resolution for the name xyz.database.windows.net timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded

Tags: windows, azure, dns, azure-sql-database, event-log

I'm connecting to an Azure SQL database using ASP.NET on W2008R2.

In the Event Log I'm getting "Name resolution for the name xyz.database.windows.net timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded."  frequently.

It does not seem to affect connectivity, but I'm curious if I can fix this by using a specific DNS server from Microsoft. Is anybody else seeing these events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're getting a specific error related to DNS resolution in the event log, I'd first have someone outside of your network try to reach the name. They should get an access denied message providing the firewall rules aren't configured to let them in. Just have them use their favorite browser to try and reach the URI.

If that works, I know there are some options on your local machine for changing your DNS options, but can't recall exactly how to do that. If you can find those and get them to work, then you're stuck trying to work with your network team to discover what's wrong with your internal DNS cache.